# Can Emacs Eshell show remote man pages in TRAMP mode?

Tags: tramp, eshell

When I'm logged in to a remote machine in eshell I can still do `man ls`. But it appears that this only work for my local man pages. If I try `man yum` I'll get a message that the yum man page is not found. However, if I log into the machine via a regular terminal and use `man yum` there the manual is shown. Is there a way to get *remote* man pages showing up when in TRAMP mode? I'd really like that because I'm running OS X locally but frequently log in to linux servers where the utilities have different options etc.

*Update:* To clarify, here's an example session:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell
~ $ cd /ssh:example.com:/
/ssh:example.com:/ $ man yum
#<buffer *Man yum*>
```

Alright! That's expected. But, regretfully, no `*Man yum*` buffer is created an these messages appear in `*Messages*`:

```
Invoking man yum in the background
Please wait: formatting the yum man page...
yum man page formatted
error in process sentinel: user-error: Can't find the yum manpage
error in process sentinel: Can't find the yum manpage
```

*Update 2:* I found out (from a comment on [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/4035/10625)) that I can invoke the remote man by prefixing with `*`, so `*man yum` -- which is an OK work-around. But it just dumps the content in the eshell window, rather than open a new buffer like the `man` command does. I'd really like that behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean `man` as the emacs command, or as the shell command?

Comment: I mean when typing `man yum` in eshell, the emacs shell. Not `M-x man`.

Comment: That's the same, because `eshell` runs in emacs. Try `\man yum` instead.

Comment: `\man yum` does not work, but `*man yum` kinda does -- I've added my "objection" to that to the question also.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957137/how-to-make-emacs-man-work-over-tramp) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a work-around! Admittedly it is a bit hacky, and uses woman
rather than man, but I think this might just work for me. Essentially,
`woman-find-file` is tramp aware, so if we can pass it the path to the remote
man page it will open it just fine.

Passing the `--path` flag to `man` will output the path of the manpage rather than open the manpage itself. Woman doesn't like pre-formatted man pages, so pass the `-c` flag to ignore those. Now we can execute the *remote* man command (by prefixing `man` with `*`) to find the path to the `foo` man page thus: `*man -c --path foo`.

The following function takes a path from the above and checks if it is a
remote path. If it is, it prepends the tramp method, user & host to the local
file name. Then it invokes the `woman-find-file` function on the result. Put
it in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

```el
(defun tramp-aware-woman (man-page-path)
  (interactive)
  (let ((dir (eshell/pwd)))
    (woman-find-file
     (if (file-remote-p dir)
         (let ((vec (tramp-dissect-file-name dir)))
           (tramp-make-tramp-file-name
            (tramp-file-name-method vec)
            (tramp-file-name-user vec)
            (tramp-file-name-host vec)
            man-page-path))
       man-page-path))))
```

Now we can create an alias that invokes our function for a bit of ux sugar:

```
alias man 'tramp-aware-woman ${*man -c --path $1}'
```

The new command should work from eshell both locally and remote, though you
will now get woman's rendering. You may want to choose a different name for
the alias if you want to retain the existing behaviour of man for local man
pages.